# How do I position a button at the bottom always? This will be rendered from a component whose parent is a scrollview

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How do I position a button at the bottom always? This will be rendered from a component whose parent is a scrollview. When I use abosolute position, positioning works, but when I scroll the view the button scrolls as well.

```
positionInBottom {
    position: 'relative',
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    top: 160 - 26,
    left: Dimensions.get('window').width - 70,
    backgroundColor: 'red,
    zIndex: 100,
}
```

Here is my componet structure: It's a sudo code.

```
<Page>
<ScrollView>
  <Items items={this.items}/>
</ScrollView>
</Page>

<Items>
{items.map((item) => {
   <Text>{item.name}</Text>
 })
}
<Button stype={styles.positionInBottom} name="stay in the bottom" label="stay in the bottom"/>
</Items>
```

The following the documentation from react native. What does the bolded lines exactly means? I don't understand it.

position ReactPropTypes.oneOf([ 'absolute', 'relative' ])

position in React Native is similar to regular CSS, but everything is set to relative by default, so absolute positioning is always just relative to the parent.

If you want to position a child using specific numbers of logical pixels relative to its parent, set the child to have absolute position.

**If you want to position a child relative to something that is not its parent, just don't use styles for that. Use the component tree.**

See https://github.com/facebook/css-layout for more details on how position differs between React Native and CSS.

Comment: Can you share more code that shows your component hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, updated the question with code.

Answer (score 2):

```
positionInBottom {
    position: 'absolute',
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    bottom: 0,
    left: Dimensions.get('window').width - 70,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    zIndex: 100,
}
```

Comment: forgot end quote at end of 'red'